# Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by pseudo base

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Can a similar result to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415201/if-mathcalb-is-a-base-of-a-topology-space-leftx-tau-right-then-the-b) be true for a topological space that has a [pseudo basis](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pseudo-basis) "A collection of non-empty open sets (in a topological space X) such that every non-empty open set of X contains one of these is called a pseudo-basis"

**Edit: Question:  If $\mathcal B$ is a countable pseudo base for a topological space $(X,\tau)$, then $\sigma(\mathcal B)=\sigma(\tau)$, where $\sigma(*)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $(∗)$.**

Comment: Can you explain what kind of "similar" result you are looking for?  The statement in the question is false and replacing "base" with "pseudo-base" would make it even more false.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is true for a topological space with a countable pseudo-base?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment. This is the question: If $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable pseudo base for a topological space $(X, \tau)$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{B})=\sigma(\tau)$, where $\sigma(*)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Please use the edit button below your question to add this to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a second-countable Hausdorff space and that $x,y$ are two distinct limit points of $X$.  Let $\{U_n\}$ be any countable basis for $X$ and let $V_n = U_n \setminus \{x,y\}$, so that $V_n$ is open, nonempty, and $V_n \subset U_n$.  Then $\{V_n\}$ is a countable pseudo-basis.  However, every set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{V_n\}$ either contains $\{x,y\}$ or is disjoint from it.  In particular, this $\sigma$-algebra does not contain the Borel set $\{x\}$.

Comment: You are great, Nate! Thanks a lot