# Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the order topology $\textit{vs.}$ $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topological subbasis

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

This is a proof-verification (or more like counterexample-verification) request.

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set and $\geq$ a linear order (a complete, transitive, antisymmetric order) on it. Define
\begin{align*}
\mathscr L\equiv&\;\big\{\{\psi\in\Omega\,|\,\psi<\omega\}\,\big|\,\omega\in\Omega\big\},\\
\mathscr U\equiv&\;\big\{\{\psi\in\Omega\,|\,\psi>\omega\}\,\big|\,\omega\in\Omega\big\}
\end{align*}
to be the family of *lower sets* and that of *upper sets*, respectively.

The *order topology* $\tau$ on $\Omega$ is the topology which has $\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U$ as its topological subbasis; it is the coarsest topology according to which all lower and upper sets are open. From this topology, one can generate the *Borel $\sigma$-algebra* $\mathscr B\equiv\sigma(\tau)$, which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra according to which sets open according to the order topology are measurable.

> My goal is to show that, in general,
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathscr B\neq\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U);\tag{$\clubsuit$}
> \end{align*}
>   that is, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the lower and upper sets is not large enough to give the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

*Remark:* In some special cases, $\mathscr B$ and $\sigma(\mathscr L\cup \mathscr U)$ do coincide—for example, when $\Omega=\mathbb R$ with the usual order, in which case the order topology is the standard Euclidean topology, whose Borel $\sigma$-algebra is well-known to be generated by $\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U$ (and even by $\mathscr L$ alone or by $\mathscr U$ alone). More generally, if the order topology $\tau$ is second-countable, then $\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U$ does generate $\mathscr B$; the details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415201/if-mathcalb-is-a-base-of-a-topology-space-leftx-tau-right-then-the-b). However, as a rule, the two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr B$ and $\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)$ may be different.

In particular, I have the following supposed counterexample in mind. Let $(\Omega,\geq)$ be the *set of countable ordinals*. This is a linearly ordered set such that

- $\Omega$ is uncountable; but
- each lower set in $\mathscr L$ is countable; furthermore,
- every non-empty subset of $\Omega$ has a least element with respect to the order $\geq$.

The first step is to show that
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)=\mathscr C,
\end{align*}
where $\mathscr C$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable sets:
\begin{align*}
\mathscr C\equiv\{A\subseteq\Omega\,|\,\text{$A$ is countable or $A^{\mathsf c}$ is countable}\}.
\end{align*}
Clearly, each set in $\mathscr L$ is countable and each set in $\mathscr U$ is co-countable, so that $\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)\subseteq\mathscr C$. Conversely, note that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, the singleton $\{\omega\}$ is the intersection of the complement of a set from $\mathscr L$ and the complement of another set from $\mathscr U$. Therefore, the singletons are in $\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)$, which implies that $\mathscr C$ is included in $\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)$.

Therefore, in order to prove ($\clubsuit$), it is sufficient to exhibit a set that is open in the order topology (and hence *a fortiori* Borel measurable) but is neither countable nor co-countable. To this end, define the *immediate-successor function* $S:\Omega\to\Omega$ as follows: for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $S(\omega)\in\Omega$ is the (unique) element of $\Omega$ such that

- $S(\omega)>\omega$; and
- there exists no $\psi\in\Omega$ such that $S(\omega)>\psi>\omega$.

More formally, $S(\omega)$ is the least element of the upper set $\{\psi\in\Omega\,|\,\psi>\omega\}$.

It is easily seen that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, one has
\begin{align*}
\{S(\omega)\}=\{\psi\in\Omega\,|\,\psi<S(S(\omega))\}\cap\{\psi\in\Omega\,|\,\psi>\omega\},
\end{align*}
so that the set
\begin{align*}
U\equiv S(\Omega)=\bigcup_{\omega\in\Omega}\{S(\omega)\}
\end{align*}
is open in the order topology. What is more, since $U$ is a union of open singletons, any subset of $U$ is open, too. In addition, the function $S$ is injective, so that $U$ is uncountable. Therefore, $U$ can be partitioned into two disjoint uncountable subsets, say $V$ and $W$. Hence, $V$ is an uncountable open set and since $W\subseteq V^{\mathsf c}$, the complement of $V$ is also uncountable. It follows that $V\notin\sigma(\mathscr L\cup\mathscr U)$. This observation concludes the construction of the desired counterexample.

Any comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could stop with $U=S(\Omega)$ because $U$ is neither countable nor co-countable.

Comment: @bof Thank you, I corrected the misplaced terminology. I couldn’t prove that $U^{\textsf c}$ (the set of limit ordinals) is not countable because I am not familiar with cardinal/ordinal arithmetic, so I took a small detour.