# If $\sigma(\mathcal B)=\sigma(\mathcal T)$ for every basis $\mathcal B$ of topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$, must $T$ be hereditarily Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

In the comments of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1415213/477746) answer, someone claims:

> If topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, then $\sigma(\mathcal B)=\sigma(\mathcal T)$ for every basis $\mathcal B$.

Can this theorem be strengthened to read "if and only if"?

---

To clarify after some discussion in the comments, I'm introducing this terminology:

A basis $\mathcal B$ for topology $\mathcal T$ has the "Borel property" if $\sigma(\mathcal B)=\sigma(\mathcal T)$.

A topology $\mathcal T$ has the "strong Borel property" if every basis for the topology has the Borel property.

The conjecture then becomes: "A topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ is hereditarily Lindelöf **if and only if** $\mathcal T$ has the strong Borel property."

Comment: The result that **yada** mentioned actually required that $X$ be **hereditarily** Lindelöf. The example in the first comment there — a strong limit cardinal of countable cofinality in its order topology — is not hereditarily Lindelöf.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, I updated my question to read "hereditary Lindelöf."

Comment: I don't know enough to understand the example. Is it a counterexample to my question? I.e., is it a space that is **not** hereditary Lindelöf, but **does** satisfy $\sigma(\mathcal B)=\sigma(\mathcal T)$ for any basis $\mathcal B$?

Comment: Yes, it’s a counterexample: it’s not hereditarily Lindelöf, since it has the non-Lindelöf subspace $\omega_1$, but every open set is the union of countably many basic open sets for a suitable choice of base.

Comment: My conjecture: Hereditarily Lindelöf $\Leftrightarrow$ Every basis has the Borel property. Suppose a space in NOT hereditarily Lindelöf and has one basis that satisfies the Borel property. This is consistent with the conjecture.

Comment: Ah, you’re right; my apologies. I’m pretty sure that the usual base of intervals does not have the property, though I’ve not actually gone through the argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reverse implication is false. To show this, consider the following counterexample of a topology with the “strong Borel property” that fails to be Lindelöf, let alone hereditarily so.

---

Let $(X,\geq)$ be the set of countable ordinals and introduce the following notation for the (strict) lower segment corresponding to a generic $x\in X$:
\begin{align*}
L_x\equiv\{y\in X\,|\,y<x\}.
\end{align*}
Recall that the set of countable ordinals has the following properties:

- $X$ is uncountable;
- $\geq$ is a total (complete, antisymmetric, and transitive) order on it;
- $L_x$ is countable for every $x\in X$; and
- every non-empty subset of $X$ has a least element according to $\geq$.

---

Consider the following family of sets:
\begin{align*}
\tau\equiv\{\varnothing,X\}\cup\{L_x\,|\,x\in X\}.
\end{align*}
This is a topology, because any union of lower segments is either a lower segment or the whole set $X$ itself (you can check this by exploiting the order structure of $(X,\geq)$), and the intersection of two lower segments is also a lower segment.

---

Let $\mathscr B$ be any topological basis for $\tau$. For any $x\in X$, the open set $L_x$ can be expressed as a union of basic open sets, which must be lower segments themselves. Formally, there exists some $W_x\subseteq X$ such that

- $L_w\in\mathscr B$ for every $w\in W_x$; and
- $L_x=\bigcup_{w\in W_x}L_w.$

But then every $w\in W_x$ must satisfy $w\leq x$, so that $W_x\subseteq L_x\cup\{x\}$. Consequently, $W_x$ is countable. Therefore, every lower segment is a countable union of basic open sets, which implies that $\tau\subseteq\sigma(\mathscr B)$. (Note that the empty set $\varnothing$ and the whole set $X$ are trivially included in $\sigma(\mathscr B)$). It readily follows that $\sigma(\tau)=\sigma(\mathscr B)$ for any topological basis $\mathscr B$, so the topological space $(X,\tau)$ has the strong Borel property.

---

Yet, it cannot be Lindelöf, since
\begin{align*}
X=\bigcup_{x\in X}L_x,
\end{align*}
and the open cover $\{L_x\}_{x\in X}$ has no countable subcover (given that a countable union of countable sets is countable).